# How to set workflow condition that runs 2AM everyday?

Tags: date, workflow, salesforce, visualforce

I am to create email alert which works together with workflow rule.

```
 My goal is to set the workflow that runs 2am everyday && 
 my custom object field 'startDate' is tomorrow.
```

Basically every 2am workflow checks my custom object and see if startDate is tomorrow.

I'm at workflow page looking at Date predefined variable,

I see:

```
DATE
DATEVALUE
DAY
MONTH
NOW
TODAY
YEAR
```

For the startDate, I can set condition `startDate = today() + 1`

For second condition which is `2am everyday` I can't think of a way. I don't see HOUR variable etc..

Has anyone done this before?

**UPDATE**

This might work I have to test though..

Change NOW() datetime output to String (done by TEXT)

Start from index 12 and grab 2 chars to the right (done by MID)

This means I obtained hour part of current time and if the value equals to '02' which means

2am at night.

```
MID(TEXT(NOW()), 12, 2) = '02'
```

Wait a sec.. but WHEN does salesforce check this workflow???

If they check workflow once a day, what time it would be? If check is done past 2am, this workflow would never get looked at??? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work flow only triggers on some event (object update, create, etc.). So having it run at 2am without a some sort of trigger is impossible.

The trick is to use [schedulable apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm) to insert an object (or update a field) every day at 2am and set your workflow to trigger on that insert/update. Then your workflow would fire off on that object at whatever time your scheduled apex ran.

Comment: So.. in order to start the cron, system.schedule() method must be called. What is the normal practice to call the method? Somewhere in the process the method have to be called. Should I just create one page with button that calls method, say, FOO and have FOO() calls system.schedule() ?